# Which is the correct way to fire an event from native to javascript with Cordova?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I couldn't find any article/blog/docs explaining how to fire an event from native Android/iOS to javascript with Cordova.

How to implement such async communication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `cordova-plugin-network-information` does it

```
var cordova = require('cordova');
cordova.fireDocumentEvent('offline');
```

Then you listen for it like this:

```
document.addEventListener("offline", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Statusbar plugin does it like this:

```
cordova.fireWindowEvent('statusTap');
```

Then you listen for it like this:

```
window.addEventListener('statusTap', yourCallbackFunction);
```

In the native part, it's just a like any other plugin callback, for the statusbar plugin it's like this for iOS

```
CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:payload];
    [result setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:_eventsCallbackId];
```

The important part is the `setKeepCallbackAsBool` set to `YES`, that's for allowing to call the callback multiple times and the callback is the one firing the event.

Comment: Whats the equivalent of `setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES ` in Swift? Thanks

Comment: I've found a good article related to this theme. 
https://adridev.com/blog/cordova-plugin-ios/